# Convert docx "Source Code" to backtick code blocks

Tags: pandoc

When converting a Word-Document to markdown Code Blocks (paragraphs styled with "Source Code") are converted as indented code blocks.

Is there a way to convert them as backtick code blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple lua filter.

Create a file `myfilter.lua` with following code:

````lua
function CodeBlock (cb)
    return pandoc.RawBlock('markdown', '```\n' .. cb.text .. '\n```\n')
end
````

And add the argument `--lua-filter myfilter.lua` to your pandoc command:

```bash
pandoc filename.docx -f docx -t markdown -o outputfile.md --lua-filter myfilter.lua
```